# Unable to determine meaning of status bar icon

Tags: macos, icon, menu-bar

I have a status bar icon that does nothing when you click on it. I have no idea what it does or what it means, it just appeared one day.  Does anyone have any ideas on its meaning?

[image]

Comment: Really interesting! If you have Xcode installed, you could use the Accessibility Inspector which will tell you what it is. Otherwise, you could download the trial for Bartender (https://www.macbartender.com) and look in its preferences to see what it is.

Comment: Take a screenshot and add it to your question, maybe someone will recognize it.

Comment: There's already a screenshot.